# Why does Genymotion need Virtualbox to run?

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

[Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/) is a new  Android Emulator that could be only used from inside a VirtualBox running Ubuntu.

Why I can't just use it in my native physical Ubuntu system?

---

**I know how to install it, I already did it, I'm asking why this doesn't work on PC. Why it does just work on VirtualBox?**

Comment: *Genymotion requires VirtualBox to run on virtual devices.* Genymotion is not in the Ubuntu repos, so beyond the simple explanation given in the first sentence the question if it requires a more detailed answer than that should be addressed to the Genymotion developers. It does save the Genymotion developers money to require an existing open source virtual machine application (VirtualBox). Otherwise they would have to write the VM software themselves.

Answer (score 2):

[Because](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide)

> Genymotion operation relies on the use of Oracle VM VirtualBox in the background. This enables virtualizing Android operating systems.

Your question seems to end in a cirle: Genymotion is a virtualBox based Android Emulator. So the answer basically ends up in: because Genymotion decided on that.

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion needs VirtualBox. It creates virtual devices (android phones). In short, VirtualBox takes some of your computer's memory and allocates that memory to a virtual device. It's all about the concept of virtualization. Without VirtualBox, you can't run [Genymotion On macOS](https://applestin.com/how-to-install-genymotion-on-macbook/), windows, or Linux.